# How to store possible values of a variable in local macro?

Tags: stata

I want to store the distinct values  of a variable of my dataset in a local macro. I thought that there could be a way using a function as `table` and storing some `r()`. But I could not find any function with an useful `r()` that returns what I want.

As an example, I would like to find an expression to substitute in the code below and get as a return a `local` with `Domestic Foreign`

```
sysuse auto
table foreign
local foreign_unique_values = r(...)
```

Comment: You need to look at `help levelsof`.

Comment: Exactly what i need, thanks!

Comment: Unique is a poor term here, despite being commonly used in this sense. Unique means occurring just once. A better term would be distinct.

Comment: You are right, i will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by William Lisowski in comments, `levelsof` does this.

In my example code would be:

```
sysuse auto
levelsof foreign
local foreign_distinct_values = r(levels)
```

or with a categorical variable:

```
levelsof make
local make_distinct_values = r(levels)
```

Comment: You  could just use the -local()- option on the command line.

Comment: Note that the distinct values in your example are 0 and 1.

Comment: Yeah, it makes more sense with a categoricalvariable.